# Firebase child is not being remove, parent is

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using react-native and am attempting to remove a child ref, my function is...

```
cancelSleep = ()=> {
  const rootRef = firebase.database().ref("SleepSettings/")
  rootRef.child(`${this.state.user}/`).remove().then( ()=>
  this.setState({sleepConfirmed: false}))
}
```

I've tried many different combinations either way the whole ref "SleepSettings" and all its children are removed as opposed to just the child ref, see pictures.[image]

Comment: many variants of reworking this function produce the same behavior, such as

cancelSleep = ()=> {
  firebase.database().ref("SleepSettings/").child(`${this.state.user}`).remove().then( ()=>
  this.setState({sleepConfirmed: false}))
}

Comment: Solved? @yazmnh87

Comment: No this has not been solved for me, thank you for asking.  I'm find the same thing when I am trying to get data as well, its only recognizing the parent ref.

Comment: getBedTime = () => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("SleepSettings/")
      .child(`${this.state.user}`)
      .once("value", snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
          const data = snapshot.val();
          console.log(data);
          this.setState(
            {
              chosenDate: new Date(data[`${this.state.user}`].bedtime),
              sleepConfirmed: data[`${this.state.user}`].sleepConfirmed
            },
            console.log(this.state)
          );
        }
      })
  };

Comment: this function above, is just returning everything in SleepSettings/ not the reference child ref of `${this.state.user}`.  I reworked this but believe that ref('SleepSettings/${this.state.user}`) should work fine.  So Im doing something wrong but have yet to figure it out.  The firebase docs seem straight forward. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Let me see your code here, https://codeshare.io/an7Erv @yazmnh87

Comment: @DevAS sorry didnt see your post until a few minutes ago, posted my code there and some comments.  Its not my complete component but am showing the functions where I calling firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Realtime Database, when a node no longer has any children, it is removed from display in the console.  What you are seeing is that the only child of SleepSettings is being removed, which means SleepSettings itself is removed from display.

In actuality, a node doesn't really exist in Realtime Database.  It's just part of a path to get to a value, such as this path:

```
SleepSettings/bill@bill/sleepConfirmed
```

Which has this value:

```
true
```

Any child that doesn't have a value attached to it is just an organizer for other children, and when all its child values are gone, the organizer is effectively gone, as there are no paths to values left to organize.

In other words, they don't work like filesystem folders at all, which exist and can be empty.

Comment: So if there were other users data, it would just remove the reference child and not the whole node?

Comment: Yes, that should be pretty easy for you to test for yourself.